# Regex - select an expression between single quotes

Tags: python, regex

My goal is to select strings like `hello_kitty.dat` from `Lorem 'hello_kitty.dat' ipsum.`.

I have written this snippet that works to some extent for smaller strings
 (from `teststring` select one or more (`+`) word characters (`\w`) before a dot (`\.`) with three word characters after that (`\w{3}`) and **sub**stitute selection with `x`).

```
>>> teststring = "Lorem 'hello_kitty.dat' ipsum."
>>> print(re.sub(r'\w+\.\w{3}', "x", teststring))

"Lorem 'x' ipsum."
```

But how would I modify the code to select everything between single quotes even if that does not follow my pattern completely after the `\w{3}`?

`teststring` could be 
`"Lorem 'hello_kitty.cmd?command91' ipsum hello_kitty.cmd?command92"` but wouldn't want to select `hello_kitty.cmd?command92` in this case since its outside of single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
import re
teststring = "Lorem 'hello_kitty.cmd?command91' ipsum hello_kitty.cmd?command92"
print(re.sub(r"'\w+\.\w{3}[^']*'", "'x'", teststring))
# => Lorem 'x' ipsum hello_kitty.cmd?command92
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/nZAYzI)

The pattern now matches:

- `'` - a single quote
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `\.` - a dot
- `\w{3}`  - 3 word chars
- `[^']*` - a negated character class matching any 0+ chars other than a single quote
- `'` - a single quote.

Comment: This code works well but I don't get how this works: `[^']*`. Is that used to capture the question-mark or perhaps everything after `\w{3}` that is not a single quote?

Comment: @Clone: I have added the explanation for `[^']*` in the answer, look: 1) `[^']` is a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches ***any** 0+ chars **other than** a single quote* - *zero or more*  is expressed with the help of the `*` quantifier.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! So basically it matches anything after `\w{3}` that is **not** a single quote? Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

To put my two cents in, you could use:

```
'[^']+' # quotes with a negated character class in between
```

---

Which in `Python` would be:

```
import re

string = """
"Lorem 'hello_kitty.dat' ipsum."
"Lorem 'hello_kitty.cmd?command91' ipsum hello_kitty.cmd?command92"
"""

rx = re.compile(r"'[^']+'")
string = rx.sub("x", string)
print(string)

# "Lorem x ipsum."
# "Lorem x ipsum hello_kitty.cmd?command92"
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! It is a very interesting **Regex**-snippet which does indeed work on this example but it will also selects all things between single quotes so it will get `'dontselect_me'` too which is not what I want in my project. I want to select things between single quotes hat match a specific relationship that I devised in my post; select everything between single quotes that is separated by a dot and has some word characters (`\w`) between before the dot and has at least 3 word characters after the dot (`.`) .

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a non-greedy regular expression:

```
import re
teststring = "Lorem 'hello_kitty.cmd?command91' ipsum hello_kitty.cmd?command92"
print(re.sub(r"'.*?'", "'x'", teststring)
```

Returns `Lorem 'x' ipsum hello_kitty.cmd?command9`

The regular expression `'.*?'` matches everything between single quotes, but takes the shortest possible string.